# Populating a page with a list linked to images

Tags: 2013, list, picture-library, picture

Sorry, my title is not very good at explaining what I'm trying to do.

I'm wondering if it is possible in sharepoint 2013 to have a page with a list of options on it and when you click on the an option it will populate boxes below with corresponding images from a folder.

So I'll have a folder full of images somewhere else which will be linked by the list, and when I choose something from the list it will grab the corresponding image(s) from the folder and display it on the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is possible. Upload your images to a Picture library and have a common column which connects your list and the picture library. Then drop webparts of your list and the picture library onto a page. Create a connection between the 2 webparts. This will allow you to filter items in the picture library based on the selected value in the list. Ensure that the connecting column between your list and picture library is unique in the list. Refer: http://blogs.technet.com/b/rajbugga/archive/2013/04/25/creating-connected-web-parts-in-sharepoint.aspx